# PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'message' of non-object

Tags: php

and thank you for dropping in to help me.

currently i am trying to bring an old mafia game up to date for my own personal use as no one uses them now, and am stuck using objects which i have never used before.

The error i get is :

> **Notice: Trying to get property 'message' of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\mafia\Send.php on line 67**

Here is the code

```
$query=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE f='$ownusername' ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 3");
$info = mysqli_fetch_object($query);

$fetch=mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM autospam LIMIT 1"));


if ($info->message == $message && $fetch->c == 1){

mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE users SET mute='1', mutedby='Spamming' WHERE username='$ownusername'");
echo "You have been muted!";

}
```

Comment: Where are you set this - $info->message ?

Comment: have updated my question thank you for the reply, i did put the whole code but started getting down votes

Comment: Coud you please var_dump($info); And show here?

Comment: I have done a var dump and the output is NULL

Comment: In php manual - Returns an object with string properties that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset. Check your sql request.

Comment: Many thanks i seem to have fixed the issue, as this was old coding, it was trying to put in an empty id into a field that auto increments which is un needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203181/discussion-between-dmitry-and-brian).

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed thanks to Dmitry, for pointing me in the right direction, i found that the id in the sql insert was the error, where it was trying to insert an empty value into an auto increment table.

I removed the ID from the sql insert and all is working perfectly